# ASP.net return json but postman shows unicode

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, api, unicode, postman

I've started using postman and my response has Unicode in it, I would like it to look "pretty" or in "Html" so I can see my table. I have clicked on the raw and pretty tab but they seem to show me the exact same thing.

*\r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n            \r\n                <th class="heading">Webinar\r\n\r\n                <th class="heading">Date\r\n\r\n                <th class="heading">Duration\r\n\r\n                <th class="heading">\r\n            \r\n\r\n                \r\n                    <a href="https://localhost:44304/Booking?AppointmentId=22" target="_blank">Navigating the SHPS valuation results\r\n\r\n                    24/05/2021\r\n\r\n                    21:55 - 22:49\r\n\r\n\r\n                        \r\n                            <a href="https://localhost:44304/Booking?AppointmentId=22" target="_blank" class="booknow">\r\n                                Find out more\r\n                            \r\n                        \r\n\r\n                \r\n        \r\n    \r\n*

How do I tell postman to remove the Unicode from the response?

Comment: Select the content type from the drop down

Answer (score 1):

The  response is formated correctly according to the content-type header from the response . If the server doesn't send back a content-type then the response won't be formated correctly you have to manually specify what data format it is:

so in the response tab select json form the dropdown

[image]